# Putting an ArrayList of an Array of JTextFields onto JPanel

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, jtextfield

I made an ArrayList of array of JtextField, but I don't know how to put it on my JPanel.

```
ArrayList <JTextField []> text_field;
text_field = new ArrayList <JTextField []> ();

for (int i = 0; i < text_field.size (); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

  }
}
```

How can I modify my double for loop to put my JTextField on the JPanel?

I have put the code that was given in the answer into my constructor and it compiled without error. However, when I run the program, the TextField that was added does not display on the GUI. Why does this happen?

```
ArrayList <JTextField []> text_field; //class variable

constructor {
  text_field = new ArrayList <JTextField []> ();

  for (int i = 0; i < text_field.size (); i++) {
    JTextField field [] = text_field.get (i);

    for (int j = 0; j < field.length; j++) {
      JTextField jtf = field [j];
      pan2.add (jtf);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this:

```
ArrayList <JTextField []> text_field;
text_field = new ArrayList <JTextField []> ();

for (int i = 0; i < text_field.size (); i++)
{
    JTextField [] arr = text_field.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
    {
        JTextField jtf = arr[j];
        // add the JTextField to the JPanel here
        // JPanel.add(jtf)
    }
}
```

You can also use for each loops like this:

```
for (JTextField [] arr : text_field)
{
    for (JTextField jtf : arr)
    {
        // add the JTextField to the JPanel here
        // JPanel.add(jtf)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... without knowing what 0 - 8 is supposed to represent in your nested for loop, I'm going to assume what you're actually trying to do is iterate through the JTextField[] array.  So here's the code:

Please take note of the modifications in the code (i.e. best practice stuff like       1. Use camelCase instead of underscores 
2. You don't need two separate lines in your textField object instantiation 
3. You can just declare the type as List in on the left hand assignment of the object 
4. You can use the diamond operator <> on the right hand side (since Java 7)

```
List<JTextField[]> textField = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < textField.size(); i++) {
    JTextField[] jtfArray = textField.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < jtfArray.length; j++) {
        add(jtfArray[i]);//add to the JPanel
    }
}
```